# Is it possible (and advisable) to create a visual studio 2010 project template from a project created from a project template?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, project-template

I have created a Visual Studio 2010 project template by simply selecting File > Export Template...

I then created a new project using that template as the basis.

Now I find, though (inevitably!), that I want to refactor the template. Can I make those changes to the new project and save *that* as a project template?

Or is it preferable to change the original project which became the current template? If so/the latter, will re-saving it as a project template via File > Export Template... save it as "templateName[1]" or something funky like that? If so, should I first remove the existing template by (presumably) deleting the corresponding .zip file directly from Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can save the modified template as a template. Simply select File > Export Template and follow the Export Template Wizard Prompts.

To manually modify an existing template the following steps are required:

1. Locate the template (likely in your documents folder under "Visual Studio 2010/My Exported Templates" folder
2. Extract the template.
3. Modify the intended files.
4. Select all extracted files, including the modified files, right click and choose Send To... > Compressed (zipped) folder.
5. Place the new zip file in the exported template directory.
6. Delete the old template (if necessary) and remove any remaining extracted files.
7. Run the "Developer Command Prompt" as admin and run: `devenv /installvstemplates`

As far as which is preferred, the preference is entirely your's -- personally, I'd find creating an altered version to be time efficient.